# ID3D11Buffer and std::array : buffer looks empty

Tags: directx11, vertex-buffer

I am having trouble at rendering vertices stored in a `std::vector`.

```
// Create and initialize the vertex buffer.
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexData) * this->vertex_data.size();
vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA resourceDataVertex;
ZeroMemory(&resourceDataVertex, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
resourceDataVertex.pSysMem = &(this->vertex_data);

HRESULT hr = pDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &resourceDataVertex, &(this->pVertexBuffer));
if (FAILED(hr)) return false;
```

`this->vertex_data` being a `std::vector<VertexData>` with `VertexData` being:

```
// Vertex data
struct VertexData {
    XMFLOAT3 v;
    XMFLOAT2 vt;
    XMFLOAT3 vn;

    VertexData(XMFLOAT3 v, XMFLOAT2 vt, XMFLOAT3 vn) : v{ v }, vt{ vt }, vn{ vn } {}
};
```

Now I'm not sure doing `resourceDataVertex.pSysMem = &(this->vertex_data);` is a good idea. I can render another mesh without problem just by changing the `ID3D11Buffer` vertex buffer (said mesh being known at compile-time and stored in a C-Array).

This time around I simply get no render at all. I triple checked my object is in sight and `vertex_data` is fully populated.

Comment: If other meshes render seamlessly check if the indices in the indexBuffer are in the right order.

Comment: Other mesh uses indices but this one doesn't : drawing it with `Draw(6, 0);`. Mesh is a cube face with just 2 triangles. Other mesh draws too with same drawing func - in a glitchy way but sure does ;) What about my pointer to data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&(this->vertex_data)` is the address of the `std::vector` container object itself, *not* the address of the data you stored in it.

Instead use `&(this->vertex_data.front())`

Comment: I guess this is what I was looking for. Testing this right now thanks (didn't know about `front()` ;) - genius mate =) thanks a lot!

Comment: `this->vertex_data.data()` is also an option after C++11

Comment: Correct. With VS 2012 or later, you can use ``this->vertex_data.data()``

Comment: Actually, ``this->vertex_data.data()`` also works with VS 2010.